# Transition on fill image using SVG

Tags: jquery, html, css, vivus

Im trying to achieve a smooth transition effect on image, after the vivus.js making a stroke it should do a smooth transition of image when it appears but its unfortunely not. With colors works great, but cant figure why its not working with image?
live example:

```js
new Vivus('hexagon', {type: 'delayed', duration: 160}, function(){
  $('#hex').attr('style', 'fill: url(#img); webkit-transition: fill 1.2s; -moz-transition: fill 1.2s; transition: fill 1.2s;')
});
```

```css
#hexagon {
 width: 110px;
 height: 110px;
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 top: 8%;
 margin-left: -55px;
}

#hex, #img  {
  stroke: #DC3522;
  stroke-width: 2;
  fill: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vivus/0.3.1/vivus.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <svg id = "hexagon" viewbox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="img" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100" height="100">
      <image xlink:href="http://graphicloads.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/iron-man-illustration.png" x="-25" width="150" height="100" />
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <polygon id="hex" points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25" />
</svg>

</body>
```

thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one :)

```js
new Vivus('hexagon', {type: 'delayed', duration: 160}, function(){
  $('#ironman').attr('style', '-webkit-animation:fillthis 0.3s forwards')
});
```

```css
#hexagon {
 width: 110px;
 height: 110px;
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 top: 8%;
 margin-left: -55px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fillthis
{
  from{
    opacity:0  
  }
  to
  {
    opacity:1
  }
}
    #hex, #img  {
      stroke: #DC3522;
      stroke-width: 2;
      fill:url(#img)
    }
    image{
      opacity:0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vivus/0.3.1/vivus.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <svg id = "hexagon" viewbox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="img" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100" height="100">
      <image id="ironman" xlink:href="http://graphicloads.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/iron-man-illustration.png" x="-25" width="150" height="100" />
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <polygon id="hex" points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25" />
</svg>

</body>
```

Comment: thanks man, didnt know that I can use id in the pattern section on image, that was tricky. Kudos for you